# How is padding calculated in this situation? Need it for making length and width same

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am trying to make a circle using css. I want it to keep a 1:1 aspect ratio even when the browser is resized. However, I'm having trouble making the width equal to the height in order to achieve this 1:1 ratio. I have tried many methods from JS to pure CSS, but none of them seem to work. My goal is to get the anchors with the ids 'circ1'-'circ4' to have the 1:1 aspect ratio. Currently, I have the width as a percentage and the height as a arbitrary pixel count which I eyeballed. I know that I can make the 1:1 ratio using this [Sample Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537806/css-height-same-as-width):

```
div {
  background:orange;
  width:20%;
  padding-top:20%;
}
```

But I also know that the padding is based on the container, which is the part that I can't seem to figure out.

Here is the site with the issue. The circles in the main body are what I am attempting to make into 'true circles' that also stay circles when the browser is resized.

http://www.somil.site90.net

Here is the layout of my HTML, which I believe is the source of the problem as the anchor is nested multiple times and every time I try to use 'padding' it gets thrown off as I'm not sure which container the padding is based on.

```
<body>
    <div id = "main">
    <div id = "yolo">Check some stuff out!</div>
    <div id = 'circles'>
    <a id = "circ1" href = #> <!--here is the anchor which I want to be 1:1-->
    <img class = app src = 'applogo.png' width = 80% height = 80%><div id = "taco">
    Applocity</div>
    </a>
    <a id = "circ2" href = #>
    <img class = python src = 'pyth.png' width = 85% height = 85%><div id = 'burr'>
    Pythings</div>
    </a>
    <a id = "circ3" href = #>
    <img class = calc src = 'calculator.png' width = 85% height = 85%><div id = 'churr'>
    Calculator Programs</div>
    </a>
    <a id = "circ4" href = #>
    <img class = fold src = 'folder.png' width = 80% height = 80%><div id = 'purr'>
    Miscellaneous</div>
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>



</body>
```

Here is the css for #circ1. The css for the other circles is almost identical, but can be seen in the page source (CTRL+F "circ2/3/4") of the site listed above.

```
#circ1 {
  background: #ff8300;
  height: 175px; //arbitrary value which I want to equal to 15% width converted to pixels
  width: 15%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin:65px 0px 100px 12%;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change `width:15%;` to `width:175px;` in `#circ1`

ie

```
#circ1 {
 background: #ff8300;
 height: 175px;
 width:175px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: relative;
 margin:65px 0px 100px 12%;
 float: left;
-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
 transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;


 }
```

Comment: he wants them to resize. this would give them a fixed size.

Comment: no ,it would not give it a fixed size,i tried and its working.

Comment: Setting a width of 175px and a height of 175px would be fixed. I've also tried and it is not resizing, as expected...

Answer (score 0):

Giving elements a constant aspect ratio on resize is a bit tricky. Take a look at [This JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/gVmq8/)

You want to give each anchor a parent div, and give these parent divs a percentage based `padding-bottom`. Give the anchors absolute positioning and size them to the size of the parent divs (`top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;`). Notice how the aspect ratio remains 1:1 when you resize.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The thing is that the anchors I have are relatively positioned and need to be kept that way.